# Alter menu structure when using Superfish menu

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

I am using [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish/) menus. I wanted to add a `<span>` tag before each `<a>` tag for menu links. I tried the following code:

```
function mytheme_menu_link($variables) {
    $element = $variables['element'];
    $sub_menu = '';
    if (empty($element['localized_options'])) {
        $element['localized_options'] = array();
    }
    $element['localized_options']['html'] = TRUE; //let l function know that our link title includes html
    $output = l($element['#title'], $element['#href'], $element['#localized_options']);
    return '<li' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '><span>' . $output . "</span></li>\n";
}
```

but it did not take any effect. Since I am using Superfish menus do I need to write any other code?

Comment: [duplicate](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16159/how-to-add-span-before-my-a-tag-only-for-main-menu-1st-level-items)?

Comment: Any update on this issue? I am having the same issue.

Comment: - Nope dude. I could not find any solution.

Comment: @anonym-developer: nope, it's not a dupe, it's a totally different question, related to Superfish module's own menu rendering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Superfish module bypasses the usual Drupal theming hooks for menus and implements its own. You will need to override the [theme_superfish()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/superfish/superfish.module/function/theme_superfish/7) function in order to change the HTML around those menu items. Copy that function out of [`superfish.module`](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/superfish/superfish.module/7) into your theme's `template.php` file. Replace the word "`theme`" in the function name with your theme's machine name, and make your edits.

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this via the administration interface. You could also override [theme_superfish_build()](http://api.drupalhelp.net/api/superfish/superfish.module/function/theme_superfish_build/7), but there's a simpler solution exactly for that task:

1. Go to `admin/structure/block`, search for the given Superfish block, and click configure. E.g. in my test Drupal, I'll edit *"Superfish 4"* block (in my case the path is the following: `admin/structure/block/manage/superfish/4/configure`):
   [image: Configuring Superfish block]
2. Scroll down to *"Advanced HTML Settings"*, expand the fieldset, and below the *"HTML Wrappers"* sub-fieldset, there will be a field called *"Around the hyperlinks"* (NOT the *"Around the hyperlinks contents"*), type in the following:

   ```
   <span class="this-is-your-span-class">,</span>
   ```

   [image: HTML Wrappers in Superfish]
3. Save block, and you're done.

---

## Screenshots

### BEFORE

[image: Superfish menu - hyperlink without a '<span>' wrapper]

### AFTER

[image: Superfish menu - hyperlink with a '<span>' wrapper]

Comment: you rock man! you just rock! 
I didn't understand what to do with the comma, so I tried 

    `,<span></span>` 

which didn't have the desirable effect, and then stumbled upon your answer :)